# Collisions in a HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I'm fairly new to Javascript and using a canvas in general and I cant get collision detection to work with my canvas walls.

I normally have a small square painted on the canvas that I can control with the arrow keys on the keyboard but it would continue past the canvas.

This is the working code without my attempts of collision detection.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <canvas id = "gameCanvas" width="400" height="400" style = "border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
       var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";

       var snake = {
           x: 5
           , y: 5
        };


       function drawSnake() {
           ctx.clearRect(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
           ctx.fillRect(snake.x ,snake.y,20,20);
       }

       window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { 
           if (event.keyCode == 39)
             snake.x += 5;
           else if (event.keyCode == 37)
             snake.x -= 5;
           else if (event.keyCode == 38)
             snake.y -= 5;
           else if (event.keyCode == 40)
             snake.y += 5;
           drawSnake();
        });

        drawSnake();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my attempt at collision detection.

```
//Wall Collision
    if(snake.x >= canvas.w || snake.x <= -1 || snake.y >= canvas.h || snake.y <= -1) {                  
        return;
    }
```

Entering this code leaves me with a blank canvas and I don't understand why.

I want the square to reset its position once it collides with the canvas wall and that's where I'm having all the trouble.

Comment: Where did you add the collision detection code?

Comment: coooooooooooooooooooollliiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiision : https://github.com/jriecken/sat-js

Comment: Also, your `<canvas>` should be in the `<body>`, not `<head>`

Comment: I added the collision code just under the addEventListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put it under `addEventListener`. Then, the `return` is ending the JS script.

You want to put your collision detection code in (the beginning of) `drawSnake()`.

See [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/89xarf61/).

---

There are also a few other things wrong with your code that I feel that I should address (all changed in the example).

- `<canvas>` should be in the `<body>` element, not the `<head>`
- `canvas` is not defined in JS (you can remove it from `ctx.canvas.width`
- change `canvas.w` and `canvas.h` to `ctx.width` and `ctx.height` in the collision detection code
- instead of `return`ing from the `drawSnake()` function, reset the snake to its default coordinates
- draw a better snake